# What typeface is used in this brand identity concept for Gem Bakery?

Tags: font-identification, serif

I found this bakery concept on [Behance](https://www.behance.net/gallery/20590179/Gem-Bakery). But I couldn't quite identify the font predominantly used

[image]
[image]

I've tried [Fontspring Matcherator](https://www.fontspring.com/matcherator), [WhatTheFont!](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) & [What Font is](http://www.whatfontis.com/).. with no luck so far!

Comment: Did you try contacting the Behance user directly?  That's your best bet.

Comment: Try taking out the G for the font matchers. It looks like the G might be a custom job based off a core font.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And the winner is..... [ATC Rosemary](https://avondaletypeco.com/fonts/atc-rosemary/)

[image]

It checks out when you look at some of the other images on the Behance project page.